# Does $\emptyset \in\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: real-numbers

The $\emptyset$ must be in $\mathbb{R}$ because every non-empty set has $\emptyset$. But if $\emptyset \in\mathbb{R}$ that that implies that there are empty holes in $\mathbb{R}$ contradicts the completeness property of real numbers.

Can you see $\emptyset$ in the real line?

Comment: The empty set is a *subset* of every set, not an *element* of every set.

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies things.

Comment: Standard nitpicking: $\emptyset=0\in\mathbb R$.

Comment: But is it?... An $\emptyset$ is a set that contains nothing. The $0$ is an element, not a set. Hence an element can't equal a set, or can it?

Comment: @MichaelHoppe nitpicking nitpicking: no, $0\in\omega$, but we define $\Bbb R$ to be(one of the ways) $\mathbb Q^\omega/\sim$ with $\Bbb Q=\omega^4$, so $\emptyset\notin\Bbb R$. You can decide to define $\Bbb R$ with $0$ in it(or with $\omega$ as the natural of the reals) but if you nitpick, nitpick correctly

Comment: It is possible to construct a field with the least upper bound property such that $\emptyset$ is an element.  But $\mathbb R$ is assumed to be a set whose elements are distinct from other mathematical objects, even though it may be isomorphic to that structure you constructed.